# Google Sheets: How to make a progress bar cap at 100% for a completion date, not show something like 462%?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have created a Gantt Chart is Google Sheets, with 4 columns: Progress, Start, Days, and Ends.

The issue I am having is when a project is completed, the percentage shown is over 100%, which makes no sense. A project should be 0% completed, 25%, 50%, 100%, etc. It should not be higher than 100%, like 462%.

Example:

- Progress: 462% (should be 100%)
- Start: 2022-10-24
- Days: 25
- Ends: 2022-11-18

| Progress | Start | Days | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 462% | 2022-10-24 | 25 | 2022-11-18 |

My formula for the progress bar / percentage is `=(DATEDIF(E10,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(E10,G10,"d")+1)`

I have tried using `IF` in my formula, to say something like `if percentage >= 100%, percentage == 100%` but I could not get it work.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169390/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of *sample data* side-by-side your _manually entered_ *desired results*. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your formula gets the correct results, but you want to ensure that the result is always less than or equal to 100%, use `min()`, like this:

```
=min( 100%, iferror(datedif(E10, today(), "d") + 1) / (datedif(E10, G10, "d") + 1) )
```

Format the result cell as **Format > Number > Percent**.

Comment: The formula assumes that the start and end dates are in columns `E:G` as described in the question. The sample data table seems to use different columns. Adjust the range references in the formula as required.

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but how do you deal with a future `start` date? This formula will show a `NUM!` error, if the date is not `today()`. What I tried was this: `=min(100%,(DATEDIF(E13,TODAY(),"d")+1)IF(NOT(TODAY(),c13=0%)/(DATEDIF(E13,G13,"d")+1)))`. I used the start date 2023-03-20, one month from now.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: The updated formula did not work as expected. The result in the progress column is "/30/18" when "0%" was expected.

Comment: Format the result cell as **Format > Number > Percent**.